# Pbm with animation on hover with solid background

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my very own website and I used this codepen

https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/vpNoNq to create an animation on my name.
It works fine until I want to **reduce the line-height of my elements without they hide each other** (see the "j" and "p" caracters).
You can take a look here :

```css
h1{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 110px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 90px;
}
h1 p{margin:0;}

/*************************************************/
/************* LETTER ANIMATION HOVER ************/
/* Thanks to https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/vpNoNq */

.letter-anim{
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.letter-anim .letter-anim-dynamic,
.letter-anim  .letter-anim-dynamic p {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all ease 0.7s;
}
.letter-anim  .letter-anim-dynamic{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.letter-anim.active .letter-anim-dynamic,
.letter-anim:hover .letter-anim-dynamic {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
.letter-anim.active  .letter-anim-dynamic p,
.letter-anim:hover .letter-anim-dynamic p {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.letter-anim-static{
    font-size: 76px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="letter-anim h1-firstname">
  <span class="letter-anim-static">
    レ・ジェーン<br/>
  </span>
  <span class="letter-anim-dynamic">
    <p>Lejeune</p>
  </span>
</h1>

<br/>

<h1 class="letter-anim h1-lastname">
  <span class="letter-anim-static">
    ジョゼーフ<br/>
  </span>
  <span class="letter-anim-dynamic">
    <p>Joseph</p>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Thank for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Just add margin-top : -10px in css for this css property letter-anim.letter-anim-dynamic p

 <h1 class="letter-anim h1-firstname">
      <span class="letter-anim-static">
        レ・ジェーン<br/>
      </span>
      <span class="letter-anim-dynamic">
        <p>Lejeune</p>
      </span>
    </h1>

    <br/>

    <h1 class="letter-anim h1-lastname">
      <span class="letter-anim-static">
        ジョゼーフ<br/>
      </span>
      <span class="letter-anim-dynamic">
        <p>Joseph</p>
      </span>
    </h1>


    h1{
        display:inline-block;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 110px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        margin:0;
        line-height: 90px;
    }
    h1 p{margin:0;}

    /*************************************************/
    /************* LETTER ANIMATION HOVER ************/
    /* Thanks to https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/vpNoNq */

    .letter-anim{
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #222;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .letter-anim .letter-anim-dynamic,
    .letter-anim  .letter-anim-dynamic p {    
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: all ease 0.7s;
      margin-top: -10px;
    }
    .letter-anim  .letter-anim-dynamic{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #222;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .letter-anim.active .letter-anim-dynamic,
    .letter-anim:hover .letter-anim-dynamic {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .letter-anim.active  .letter-anim-dynamic p,
    .letter-anim:hover .letter-anim-dynamic p {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .letter-anim-static{
        font-size: 76px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the container for the `h1` is just bit too small for the characters that are inside. 
Try adding a simple `padding:10px` to `h1` and the container should have more space for them.